What is the rationale behind "extension by overriding" method of inheritance, as seen in Odoo's http.Controller?
Question:
With regards to OOP inheritance, what is the rationale/use case for extension by overriding as opposed to the standard extension by inheritance?
Regarding OOP, as far as I have learnt, classes tend to follow a structure like:
  A
 / \
B   C

And via inheritance, we can have classes B and C do specialized functions whilst hosting common functions within A.
However, while experimenting with Odoo's Controller class, I came to realize that on the surface, the Controller class looks like a typical Python class but instead of the usual inheritance logic, the Controller class has its subclasses override the base class (as mentioned in their docs).
Thus, with the same structure above and assuming subclasses are loaded/initialized from left to right, the Controller starts off with A, then is extended and overridden by functions from B and finally C.
As I have never encountered this before, I just wanted to understand what are the benefits of doing this.
The only benefit I could think of is that Controller class logic can be abstracted from users/developers but still be extended to customize functionality, or that only 1 controller needs to be instantiated as opposed to 1 per subclass.
Context:
From what I have read and seen in practice in Odoo, for each class that inherits the odoo.http.Controller class, a "base controller" is created from that class that tracks every class that subclasses it (using a dict(list) updated via _init_subclass()). For every subclass in this list, the "base controller" is overridden in sequence that the subclasses are loaded and this naturally leads to methods/static variables with the same name being replaced and "new" methods/variables being added to the "base controller".
However, this method of "inheritance" becomes problematic when I have 2 controllers that need to perform very similar functions that depend on different values. Where OOP has taught me to just nest common functions within the parent controller and scope specialized functions in the children controller, this method of override inheritance basically kills specialization since scope doesn't exist outside of the "base controller".
To give a scenario, say I have the following controllers:
class MainController(http.Controller):
  key = 1
  def __init_subclass__(cls):
    # Not very sure what they would be doing here or how they cause this overriding

  def _get_values_from_db(self, table):
    # orm logic etc

  @route(["/"])
  def get_values_from_db(self):
    return self._get_values_from_db("animals")

class SubControllerAnimals(http.Controller):
  key = 2

  @route(["/animals"])
  def get_values_from_db(self):
    return self._get_values_from_db("animals")

  def animal_only_function(self):
    return self.key

class SubControllerPlants(http.Controller):
  key = 3

  @route(["/plants"])
  def get_values_from_db(self):
    return self._get_values_from_db("plants")

  def plant_only_function(self):
    return self.key * 2

This is roughly how I had implemented my controllers in Odoo, basing my logic on the typical OOP inheritance that I would get 2 different routes running through mostly similar code but returning different values. I had intended to do this as each of the sibling controllers would have generated information in identical formats, just pulling data from different tables and having to be accessed via different links from a page.
For the sake of maintainability, I would also have the habit of giving similar subclass methods the same name so that I would identify them as "doing the same thing in the other sibling classes".
However, via Odoo's extension by overriding, we end up with:
class MainController(http.Controller):
  key = 3

  def _get_values_from_db(self, table):
    # orm logic etc

  # @route(["/"]) and @route(["/animals"]) overridden due to same method name
  @route("/plants)
  def get_values_from_db(self):
    return self._get_values_from_db("plants")

  def animal_only_function(self):
    return self.key # 3

  def plant_only_function(self):
    return self.key * 2 # 6

Where methods of the same name in sibling classes are overridden by the last subclass to load instead of having both the /animals and /plants routes.
This would leads to an issue (potential programming trick?) where functions are no longer scoped to their classes and now an AnimalController could call upon a plant_only_function it would work as long as their load orders are configured properly.
Thus, the only solution I can see is that I have to give up on using the Controller class as per OOP and declare a separate controller for each "would be subclass", which would involve alot of repetitive code. Or I guess helper classes to pair with or substitute each of these controllers to restore OOP inheritance.
TLDR:
Why extend classes by overriding the parent class with subclasses instead of using specialized child classes via classic OOP inheritance?
